# Parsing kml files using Java in eclipse

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, kml

I am pretty new to Java and I'm not entirely sure how to go about reading KML files in Java. I mainly need it to spit out coordinates to be used to compare your location to another. I'm wondering whether this code gives me KML from XML or reads the KML/XML and converts it into Java.

Currently I get errors including:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    PlaceMark cannot be resolved to a type
    PlaceMark cannot be resolved to a type
    LookAt cannot be resolved to a type
    LookAt cannot be resolved to a type
    Point cannot be resolved to a type
    Point cannot be resolved to a type
    Polygon cannot be resolved to a type
    Polygon cannot be resolved to a type
    Coordinates cannot be resolved to a type
    Coordinates cannot be resolved to a type
    Coordinates cannot be resolved to a type
    Coordinates cannot be resolved to a type
    Coordinates cannot be resolved to a type
    Coordinates cannot be resolved to a type
    NetworkLink cannot be resolved to a type
    NetworkLink cannot be resolved to a type

    at org.eclipse.stem.ui.ge.kml.KmlDoc.main(KmlDoc.java:385)
```

---

```
package org.eclipse.stem.ui.ge.kml;
/*******************************************************************************
 * Copyright (c) 2006 IBM Corporation and others.
 * All rights reserved. This program and the accompanying materials
 * are made available under the terms of the Eclipse Public License v1.0
 * which accompanies this distribution, and is available at
 * http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html
 *
 * Contributors:
 *     IBM Corporation - initial API and implementation
 *******************************************************************************/ 
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.eclipse.stem.ui.ge.GELog;
import org.w3c.dom.CDATASection;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Text;



/**
 * Utility class used for Google Earth KML support.
 * 
 *  This class is used to build a KML file to be passed to
 *  Google Earth.  
 *  
 *  It basically creates an XML file using KML related arguments.
 *  
 *  See the example in the "main()" method for an example of 
 *  how to use the class.
 * 
 *
 *
 */
public class KmlDoc {



    /**
     * This class name
     */
    private static final String _className = "KmlDoc";



    /**
     * 
     * A KML document
     */
    private Document _doc;

    //private Element _root = null;

    /**
     * Construct an instance of KmlDoc.
     * 
     * The Document object is created but nothing is put
     * into it.
     * 
     */
    public KmlDoc() {
        String methodName = _className + ".KmlUtil(constructor) ";
        // Create a new parser using the JAXP API (javax.xml.parser)
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = null;
        try {
            docBuilder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            if (docBuilder != null)
              _doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
            debug(methodName+ " Error configuring xml document builder"
                    + pce.getMessage());
        }// try



    } // constructor

    /**
     * Setup the root of the KML document.
     * 
     * 
     * @param xmlns Value for xmlns 
     * (if null,  use default "http://earth.google.com/kml/2.0")
     * @return xml element
     */

    public Element setRoot(String xmlns) {
        //String methodName = _className + ".setRoot ";
        if (xmlns == null)
          xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1";     

        Element root = _doc.createElement("kml");
        root.setAttribute("xmlns",xmlns);
        _doc.appendChild(root);
        return root;
    } // 


    /**
     * 
     * Write an Xml document to an outputStream
     * 
     *
     * @param xmlFileName_
     */

    public  void writeFile(String xmlFileName_) {

        try { 

            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(xmlFileName_);  
            write(outputStream);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            debug(e);
        }
   }
    /**
     * 
     * Write an Xml document to an outputStream
     * 
     *
     * @param os Allocated output Stream
     */

    public  void write(OutputStream os) {
        try {
            // Use a Transformer for output
            TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer();
            // turn on indentations
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

            // the document source
            DOMSource docSource = new DOMSource(_doc);

            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(os);

            // output the doc
            transformer.transform(docSource, result);

            os.flush();

            os.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            debug(e);
        }
    } // end write


    /**
     * Display the current Kml document on stdOut.
     *   <br>
     *      * 
     * 
     */

    public void display() {

        try {

            // Use a Transformer for output
            TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer();
            // turn on indentations
            transformer.setOutputProperty("indent", "yes");


            // the document source
            DOMSource docSource = new DOMSource(_doc);

            // the stream

            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);

            // output the doc
            transformer.transform(docSource, result);




        } catch (Exception e) {
            debug(e);
        }
    } // end display

    /**
     * debug output method 
     * @param msg 
     */
    public void debug(String msg) {
        GELog.debug(this,msg);

    }


    /**
     * debug output method 
     * @param method 
     * @param msg 
     */
    public void debug(String method,String msg) {
        GELog.debug(this,method+msg);

    }

    /**
     * debug output method 
     * @param t 
     */
    public void debug(Throwable t) {
        GELog.error("KmlDoc failure",t);

    }
    /**
     * debug output method 
     * @param msg 
     * @param t 
     */
    public void debug(String msg,Throwable t) {
        GELog.error("KmlDoc: "+msg,t);

    }

    /**
     * @return Returns the _doc.
     */
    public Document getDocument() {
        return _doc;
    }

    /**
     * @param _doc The _doc to set.
     */
    public void setDocument(Document _doc) {
        this._doc = _doc;
    }
    /**
     * Utility method to Create an element that has 
     * a name and value only. 
     * <pre>
     * There is probably a better way to do this but ...
     *  
     *   
     *   
     * * @param doc Document
     * @param tag  xml tag
     * @param value  string value of tag
     * @return XML element
     */

    public static Element createAttr(Document doc,String tag,String value) {

        Element nm = doc.createElement(tag);
        Text t = doc.createTextNode(value);
        nm.appendChild(t);        
        return nm;
    }
    /**
     * Utility method to Create an element that has 
     * a name and CData value only. 
     * <pre>
     * There is probably a better way to do this but ...
     *  
     *   
     *   
     * * @param doc Document
     * @param tag  xml tag
     * @param value  string value of tag
     * @return XML element
     */

    public static Element createCDataAttr(Document doc,String tag,String value) {

        Element nm = doc.createElement(tag);
        Text t = doc.createCDATASection(value);
        nm.appendChild(t);        
        return nm;
    }
    /**
     * Utility method to append an element that has 
     * no values. 
     * <pre>     
     *  Creates an XML tag and
     *  places it in the document as a child of the 
     *  specified element.
     *  
     *   Creates <tag>value</tag> 
     * </pre>
     * 
     * 
     * @param element existing element where new tag is to go
     * @param tag XML tag
     * 
     * @return XML element
     */

    public Element appendElement(Element element,String tag) {

        Element newtag = _doc.createElement(tag);       
        element.appendChild(newtag);
        return newtag;
    }

    /**
     * Utility method to Create an element that has 
     * a name and Text value only. 
     * <pre>     
     *  Creates an XML tag with a text value  and
     *  places it in the document as a child of the 
     *  specified element.
     *   Creates <tag>value</tag> 
     * </pre>
     * 
     * 
     * @param element existing element where new tag is to go
     * @param tag XML tag
     * @param value value of tag
     * @return XML element
     */

    public Element appendText(Element element,String tag,String value) {
        // if obvious XML tag then treat it special
        if (value.indexOf("<")>=0 || 
            value.indexOf(">")>=0 ) {
            return appendCDATA(element,tag,value);
        }
        Element nm = _doc.createElement(tag);
        Text t = _doc.createTextNode(value);
        nm.appendChild(t);        
        element.appendChild(nm);
        return nm;
    }

    /**
     * Utility method to append an element that has 
     * a name and CData value only. 
     * <pre>
     * 
     *  
     *   <tag>value of tag with  html in it</tag>
     * </pre>
     * 
     * 
     * @param element existing element where new tag is to go
     * @param tag XML tag
     * @param value value of tag
     * @return XML element
     */
    public Element appendCDATA(Element element,String tag,String value) {

        Element nm = _doc.createElement(tag);
        CDATASection cdata = _doc.createCDATASection(value);
        nm.appendChild(cdata);        
        element.appendChild(nm);
        return nm;
    }

    /**
     * Utility method to Create an element that has 
     * a name and boolean value only. 
     * <pre> 
     *  <tag>1</tag> or <tag>0</tag>
     *   
     * </pre>
     * 
     * @param doc root document
     * @param element existing element where new tag is to go
     * @param tag XML tag
     * @param value true or false
     * @return XML element
     */

    public Element appendAttr(Element element,String tag,boolean value) {

        Element nm = _doc.createElement(tag);
        String strValue = (value)? "1" : "0";

        Text t = _doc.createTextNode(strValue);
        nm.appendChild(t);        
        element.appendChild(nm);
        return nm;
    }
    /**
     * main class used for debug
     * @param args
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       KmlDoc kml = new KmlDoc();
       Document doc = kml.getDocument();
       Element root = kml.setRoot(null);
       Element folderA = doc.createElement("Folder");
       root.appendChild(folderA);
       Element folderA1 = doc.createElement("Folder");
       folderA.appendChild(folderA1);
       PlaceMark placeMark = new PlaceMark(doc);
       folderA1.appendChild(placeMark.getElement());
       //placeMark.setDescription("Homebase");
       kml.appendText(placeMark.getElement(),"description",
               "Home at<br>119 Third");
       placeMark.setName("Home");

       LookAt lookat = new LookAt(doc);
       lookat.setCoordinates(-122.0059,36.9639);
       lookat.setRange(305.8880792294568);
       lookat.setTilt(46.72425699662645);
       lookat.setHeading(49.06133439171233);
       placeMark.appendChild(lookat.getElement());

       //placeMark.setVisibility("0");
       kml.appendAttr(placeMark.getElement(),"visibility",false);
       Point point = new Point(doc);
       point.setCoordinates(-122.0059,36.9639);
       placeMark.appendChild(point.getElement());

       Element folderA2 = doc.createElement("Folder");
       folderA.appendChild(folderA2);

       Polygon polygon = new Polygon(doc);
       Coordinates[] corners = new Coordinates[4];
       corners[0] = new Coordinates(-122.0059,36.9639);
       corners[1] = new Coordinates(-122.0049,36.9639);
       corners[2] = new Coordinates(-122.0049,36.99);
       corners[2] = new Coordinates(-122.0059,36.9639);
       polygon.setCoordinates(corners);
       folderA2.appendChild(polygon.getElement());

       Element folderA3 = doc.createElement("Folder");
       folderA.appendChild(folderA3);

       NetworkLink netLink = new NetworkLink(doc);
       String urlfile = "c:/tmp/test.kml";
       int interval = 6;
       netLink.setUrl(urlfile, interval,null);
       folderA3.appendChild(netLink.getElement());

       kml.display();
       kml.writeFile("test1.kml");
    }

}
```

Comment: "I'm wondering whether this code gives me kml from xml or reads the kml/xml and puts it into java." What did it do, when you tested it?

Comment: It gave me several errors and I couldn't figure out how to get it to work. I also don't have access to any files to test it yet. I've just been given the project and told to find code that works for it.

Comment: How about you edit the question and post the errors that you're getting then?

Comment: All those `cannot be resolved to a type` problems are because you've not defined the classes in the file nor imported them. Thus the compiler doesn't know where to find them.

Comment: Ok i've been stuck on errors like these in many of my attempts at this problem. How do I go about defining the classes/importing them?

Comment: Where did you find said classes? If they're in your project libraries or dependencies you can just choose "Source / Organize imports" from the Eclipse dropdown menus and Eclipse will generate the import rows for them. If that doesn't work, then you need to add the packages where said classes are defined into your build path via right clicking the project on Package Explorer and choose "Build Path / Configure Build Path..."

Comment: Ok so anything that is listed in the errors needs to have a package named after it? If so what do i put in the package?

Comment: Every class needs to either be defined in your projects source code or in a dependency package (generally xxx.jar). You cannot just magic out classes as you go.

Comment: @t0mppa   I guess more what I am asking is what are the classes that need to be defined/given their own package. I understand I can't just make them disappear but I have no clue what the ones that disappear are and how to define them. I guess I'm more asking for pointers on what I need to change and how to go about it.

Comment: You need to define classes for `PlaceMark`, `LookAt`, `Point`, `Polygon`, `Coordinates` and `NetworkLink`, since those aren't classes defined by Java core libraries. Might be a good time to do a Java tutorial and learn more about creating custom classes or then use data structures defined by Java core?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have all the imports of this class in your class path?
Your problem doesn't seem KML related.

Comment: I see what you are saying by that it isn't KML related. The errors are not, however I was hoping someone who had knowledge of kml  could help me in determining whether the code would out put kml or java.

Comment: I am not a kml expert but the java code seems to indicate that the output are kml  KmlDoc kml = new KmlDoc(); and   kml.writeFile("test1.kml");

Comment: Ok thanks for your input, I have a feeling it is correct. Hopefully I can figure out how to solve the errors.

Comment: Do you have this class in your project PlaceMark? If not you ha to find the missing classes (jar or java file)

Comment: The only stuff I have is listed in the code. So no I do not have it in my project placemark. is PlaceMark equivalent to a place holder and then just sub in my actual project's name? Or is it a file i need to acquire the same way I got the code?

Comment: Yes you have to find the code and add the files listed as "cannot be resolved to a type" to your project. But in order to save you some time you should take a java tutorial to properly understand what your are doing.

Comment: ok thanks for the help any links to a java tutorial or should I just buy a book?

Comment: I don't start googling there is too long time I started learning Java to know and I used mostly books and tutorials in my mother tongue at first. You should try a book first. I let other advise you on good books to learn Java.